# Laravel + Ubuntu + PHP5 - Changes not taking effect

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I made a bunch of changes to my site, uploaded to live server and none of my changes are taking effect.

I've restarted the VPS & apache2. If I view my index.blade.php(Home route) in nano from SSH, the changes are there. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: try deleting files in the view inside storage folder `(app/storage/views)`

Comment: Yup just did that and it worked. If you want to make a comment I will mark it as the answer! Thank you!!!

Comment: I have lost hours to figure this out , this answer may help others out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try deleting files in the `view` inside `storage` folder `(app/storage/views)` . Which contains the cache of the view files